# Why does Bike2.getTime() returns a 0 instead of a correct integer value?

Tags: java

Hey Guys I am learning java i wrote this simple code i can not find any error. i can't get Bike2 .getTime.  thanks for reading

```
public class ConstructorEx3 {

        int Speed;
        int Distance;
        int Minute;
        public int getTime (){
            return  ((Distance/Speed)*Minute);  
        }
        ConstructorEx3 (){
            Distance = 60;
            Speed    = 30;
            Minute   = 60;
        }
        ConstructorEx3 (int D, int S, int M){
            Distance = D;
            Speed    = S;
            Minute   = M;
        }
        public static void main (String []arsh){
            ConstructorEx3 Bike1,Bike2;
            Bike1 = new ConstructorEx3();
            Bike2 = new ConstructorEx3(40,80,60);

        System.out.println("Bike one is travelling at : "+ Bike1.getTime());
        System.out.println("Bike two is travelling at : "+ Bike2.getTime());

        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "I can't get Bike2.getTime()'?

Comment: Please actually *describe* the problem.  Don't assume we know what this code is supposed to be doing or what you see when you run it.

Comment: @bcsb1001 : it's right above his constructors

Comment: Use Java naming conventions - fields, local variables, methods, constructors and parameters should all have camelCase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's integer operation `(40/80)*60` will give you `0`. Note here that in integer calculation `40/80` will be `0` not `0.5` you need to use [`double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) values instead of `int` in your program to get exact answer (*for your particular case*).

Some suggestions related to *conventions*,

- Choose meaningful name for your class which describe it's purpose i.e `TimeCalculator`, `Bike`
- Start variable name with small letter `distance` not `Distance`
- Same way instance variable name should also start with small letter `bike1` and not `Bike1`
- Better to use `this.distance` in constructor instead of `Distance = D`

Comment: Note: this isn't **exact** - that would be `BigDecimal` - it's just the best option here, as extra precision is not important.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I didn't mean it for all cases *though*. But yes I agree with that.

Comment: Please qoute his code and fix the coding convension for him, bro

Comment: @HungPV Fixing whole code is not a good way to help him to learn something and that will be considered as a *spoon feeding*. I tried to add some suggestions in my answer related to the convention.

Comment: thanks Task it make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
Distance = 40;
Speed = 80;
Minute - 60;

Distance / Speed = 0.5;
```

Since you are working with an `int`, the `.5` is cascaded. Finally, you get `0 * Minute = 0 * 60  = 0;`

The best way is to convert the value as `double` and convert back. Note that it's lossy as you don't get accurate results when dealing with double to int conversion.

See how I solved your problem in the `getTime()` method:

```
public class ConstructorEx3 {

        int Speed;
        int Distance;
        int Minute;
        public int getTime (){
            double v = ((double)Distance/(double)Speed);
            v= v * (double)Minute;
            return (int)v;
//          return  ((Distance/Speed)*Minute);    
        }
        ConstructorEx3 (){
            Distance = 60;
            Speed    = 30;
            Minute   = 60;
        }
        ConstructorEx3 (int D, int S, int M){
            Distance = D;
            Speed    = S;
            Minute   = M;
        }
        public static void main (String []arsh){
            ConstructorEx3 Bike1,Bike2;
            Bike1 = new ConstructorEx3();
            Bike2 = new ConstructorEx3(40,80,60);

        System.out.println("Bike one is travelling at : "+ Bike1.getTime());
        System.out.println("Bike two is travelling at : "+ Bike2.getTime());

        }
}
```

Output:

```
Bike one is travelling at : 120 
Bike two is travelling at : 30
```

Comment: thanks Buhake Sindi i got answer